# XSSFPivotTable Unable to add Report Filter

Tags: java, excel, apache, maven, apache-poi

I am working on a project where I need to create a PivotTable from an exisiting Excel file. I am able to load the file in and create a PivotTable, but when I want to set the filter for the Pivot Table I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTPageFields
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPivotTableDefinitionImpl.addNewPageFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPivotTable.addReportFilter(XSSFPivotTable.java:410)
    at com.mycompany.testmaven.PivotTable.main(PivotTable.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPageFields
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Below is my code:

```
package com.mycompany.testmaven;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataConsolidateFunction;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPivotTable;


public class PivotTable {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                /* Read the input file that contains the data to pivot */
                FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\NameOfFile.xlsx"));    
                /* Create a POI XSSFWorkbook Object from the input file */
                XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
                /* Read Data to be Pivoted - we have only one worksheet */
                XSSFSheet sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
                /* Get the reference for Pivot Data */
                AreaReference a=new AreaReference("A1:O136448");
                /* Find out where the Pivot Table needs to be placed */
                CellReference b=new CellReference("S5");
                /* Create Pivot Table */
                XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(a,b);
                /* Add filters */
                pivotTable.addDataColumn(8, true);
                pivotTable.addReportFilter(8);
                //pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

                //pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2); 
                /* Write Pivot Table to File */
                FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\POI_XLS_Pivot_Example.xlsx")); 
                my_xlsx_workbook.write(output_file);
                input_document.close(); 
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Java 8, Apache Maven 3.3.9 and Apache POI 3.15.

Comment: [Does this Apache POI FAQ entry not exactly cover you](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Although your link provides the solution, may I ask why apache poi within the default download does not provides at least all the necessary ooxml-schemas which are needed for using the high level apache poi classes? I mean, an extra download may be necessary if one would use the low level classes. But that's not the case here.

Comment: @AxelRichter It should be in the FAQ. POI ships with all the default ones, which is a few mb. Most people only need that, not the huge 20+mb full one!